# Configure Nginx to route call to upstream server using corporate http proxy

Tags: nginx, squid, http-proxy

I have a third party application which need to access an HTTPS URI on a remote location.
Here are my constraints:

1. Access to remote URI need to go through a corporate HTTP PROXY
2. Calls need to have specifics security headers
3. Need to use docker images

Here is my limitations:

1. Third party software does not provide HTTP PROXY configuration
2. Third party software does not provide setting for customer headers.
3. I cannot modify third party app.

Here is what I can do:

1. Configure REMOTE URI in the third party app.
2. Use any docker image available on docker hub.

I was thinking about tunneling the calls to the remote HTTPS URI using a reverse proxy.

THIRD PARTY APP => NGINX (add security headers) => HTTP PROXY -> REMOTE URI

I tried to use the proxy_pass with the upstream modules in NGINX without success.
Maybe I have not the right approach and should use SQUID instead of NGINX, what do you think ?

Comment: strange behavior you like to do, i am unsure how http proxy usually forward but it might work like proxy_pass http://proxy:8080/$scheme://$host$request_uri; its just a guess but not tested.

Comment: not working because nginx doesn't support the CONNECT protocol

Comment: then i belive it will not work with nginx, you may try aot-cahcer or apt-cacher-ng and allow all requests then he will act as a proxy and as i guess it can handle requests like i told